# Ubuntu 20.04 screen randomly freezes regularly

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, freeze, gpu

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and regularly, there is a brief high CPU (one core reaches 100% for a second) usage which causes the screen to freeze. I is highly noticeable and annoying when watching videos.
Did someone encounter that before?

**EDIT:** I think it is due to chrome not using the GPU even though the settings are allowing it...

Comment: Impossible to help without data. Execute `dmesg -w`in a terminal and let it run. When that 100% peak comes, check the terminal - copy that part and paste it into your question..

Comment: @kanehekili sure, I'm more than willing to communicate the data that might help debug. I let `dmesg -w` run for a long time and nothing happens. It occurs to me like the issue only appears when I'm playing youtube videos...

Comment: Well, try to reproduce the error. Besides the command above you should check (after the crash) `journcalctl -xe`, it might also have some information

Comment: @kanehekili ubuntu does not crash, it only freezes for an instant (long enough for it to be super annoying) regularly (sometimes every 20 seconds or so). So I do not have to chase the issue, it kinda always happens... Is `journalctl` still relevant?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "freeze" (I assume it's a gpu crash which will recover) So you should see it in `dmesg` and/or `journalctl`. If no sign of an error occurs in these sources, it might be within the graphics driver (whatever driver you are using, you didn't mention)

Comment: @kanehekili It seems like the freezes were coming from using the integrated GPU (intel). I set prime to use the dedicated GPU (nvidia driver version 455.23.05). I used prime to switch to the nvidia GPU and I cannot see freezes anymore but now it heats a lot... `dmesg` and `journalctl` both mention `mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 505)` followed by `mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal`

Comment: try to blacklist the integrated intel GPU (google for it) so that only the nvidia GPU is visible - you might have a thermal problem in your hardware.